# Make Selenium wait for a file download to finish

Tags: java, file, firefox, selenium, download

I managed to download the file silently with Selenium. But Firefox automatically renames the file by adding 1,2,3.. to file names as each file sent by the server has the same name. But I want to rename the files based on current date & time. So, tried:

1. Start downloading the file-> downloadLink.click();
2. While( NOT file-With-original-name exists OR <filename>.part exists)
          { `Thread.sleep(2000);` }
3. Rename the downloaded file to desired name.

But it renames some files. And some are 0 length and the last file is not even renamed. I think this is because my code continues after download and doesn't poll in the while loop. What should I do ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First you could delete from your disk the file to avoid firefox automatic renaming and then, If you know the size of the file you could check it on your loop.

Comment: I can "move" (not delete) the file only after the download is complete and my question is how do I know that it has completed ?

Comment: Do you know The size of The file?. If you know it, you could add that condition to while loop. Wait until file exists and reach that size

Comment: can you please share your selenium code?

Answer (score 0):

I would get your automation to move the file into a different location and rename it. `System.IO.File.Move("oldfilename", "newfilename");` (C#)

Possibly add a datetime onto the end of the file name.

That way you will never have the problem with duplicate file names and not being able to find the correct file.

Comment: I can't, Please refer to my comment above. My problem is not renaming but finding when Firefox completes the download.

Answer (score 0):

double fileSize = file.length();
while (!file.exists() || fileSize == 0) { Thread.sleep(2000); }

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to rename file once it is done with download.

Also I would suggest you to clear any .part file as startup pre-condition. Then before you get into while loop, depending on your computer speed and internet speed, make Thread.sleep(); let's say thread.sleep for 5k miliseconds.

Then enter while loop and look for .part file. Look for file ending with .part. If it exists, wait for another 5k miliseconds.

This solution has worked for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

The trick that I used was to open the download manager page and expect by one element that indicate that the download is finished. Follow the Python code used:

```py
# Wait until the download finish. This code just works for one single download at time on Firefox.
# browser.execute_script('window.open();')
# ActionChains(browser).key_down(Keys.COMMAND).send_keys('t').key_up(Keys.COMMAND).perform()
browser.get('about:downloads')
# files = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('download-state')
WebDriverWait(browser, URL_LOAD_TIMEOUT).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'downloadIconShow')))
# 'downloadIconCancel'
```

The problem of this approach is that it may be dependent of Firefox version, if Mozilla change that download manager page.